# Hilbert's Theorem 90 for polynomial rings

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology

I have seen here: [Silverman *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* Problem 1.12 (a)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950705/silverman-arithmetic-of-elliptic-curves-problem-1-12-a) that $H^1(G_{\overline{K} / K}, \overline{K}^+) = 0$ implies that $H^1(G_{\overline{K} / K}, I(V)) = 0$, where $I(V)$ is a prime ideal in $\overline{K}[X]$ (based on the comments it looks like the assumption that $I(V)$ is prime is unnecessary), but I'm not able to follow the reasoning for why this is the case.

Could someone provide additional explanation for how we can write an element of $Z^1(G_{\overline{K}/ K}, I(V))$ as a linear combination of elements in $Z^1(G_{\overline{K} / K}, \overline{K}^+)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $V$ is defined over $K$, there exists $b_1,\dots,\in K[X]$ defined over $K$ that forms a basis for $I(V)$. This is also a $\bar{K}$-basis for $I(V)\bar{K}[X]$.

Now, by hypothesis $F^\sigma - F \in I(V)\bar{K}[X]$. So, we have $F^\sigma -F = \sum_j c_j(\sigma)b_j$, with almost all $c_j(\sigma)=0$. The claim is that $c_j(\sigma)$ are cocycles of $\bar{K}^+$. We use the fact that $F^\sigma - F$ is a cocyle:

$$F^{\sigma\tau} - F =\sum_j c_j(\sigma\tau)b_j  $$
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
F^{\sigma\tau} - F &=& (F^\sigma-F)^\tau  + (F^\tau-F)\\
&=&\left(\sum_j c_j(\sigma)b_j\right)^\tau + \sum_j c_j(\tau)b_j \\
&=&\left(\sum_j c_j(\sigma)^\tau b_j^\tau \right) + \sum_j c_j(\tau)b_j \\
&=&\sum_j (c_j(\sigma)^\tau + c_j(\tau))b_j
\end{eqnarray*}
Comparing coefficients gives
$$c_j(\sigma)^\tau + c_j(\tau)=c_j(\sigma\tau) $$
and so each $c_j$ is a cocycle of $\bar{K}^+$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see that since $I(V)$ is defined over $K$, there are $b_1, ..., b_n$ that generated $I(V)$ *as an ideal of $K[X]$*, but this argument seems to use that the $c_j : G_{\overline{K}/ K} \to \overline{K}^+$, so we would need that $b_1, ..., b_n$ generated $I(V)$ as a $\overline{K}$-vector space. I don't see why $I(V)$ would even be necessarily finite dimensional as a $\overline{K}$-vector space though?

Comment: Just to follow-up, let's say $I(V) = \langle X, Y \rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$. Then $I(V)$ is not finitely generated as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Looks like you don't need that $I(V)$ is a finite dimensional vector space. I've edited my answer.